# SSIS Script Component - will only work in debug mode

Tags: .net, ssis

I have an annoying problem.

I have a SSIS Script Component (the one in the Data Flow to avoid confusion) that is calling a GET REST API. Now I'm a SSIS person, but have cobbled together a .net script, with some help that works, but only when there are breakpoints set, even if they are disabled.

As soon as I remove the breakpoints, I get the following error.

> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSVariables100.get_Item(Object Index)
>      at Variables.get_AddressBookIdDownload()
>      at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows()
>      at UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)

Someone (reasonably) asked what the .net code was, in order to troubleshoot ... So I've pasted it below ... Including all the field mappings in case that is the issue ...

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
#endregion

#region
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {

         //Get SSIS Variables
        string apiUserName = Variables.APIUsername;
        string apiPassword = Variables.APIPassword;
        int campaignId = (int) Variables.Campaign;

        //Set Webservice URL
        string wUrl = "https://api.aaaaaaaa.com/" + String.Concat(campaignId, "/summary");
        String base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiUserName + ":" + apiPassword));
        try
        {
            //Call getWebServiceResult to return our WorkGroupMetric array
            RootObject[] outPutMetrics = GetWebServiceResult(wUrl, base64 );

            //For each group of metrics output records
            //these are the column names defined in output columns in object
            foreach (var metric in outPutMetrics)
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();

                Output0Buffer.dateSent = (metric.dateSent);
                Output0Buffer.numUniqueOpens = metric.numUniqueOpens;
                Output0Buffer.numUniqueTextOpens = metric.numUniqueTextOpens;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalUniqueOpens = metric.numTotalUniqueOpens;
                Output0Buffer.numOpens = metric.numOpens;
                Output0Buffer.numTextOpens = metric.numTextOpens;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalOpens = metric.numTotalOpens;
                Output0Buffer.numClicks = metric.numClicks;
                Output0Buffer.numTextClicks = metric.numTextClicks;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalClicks = metric.numTotalClicks;
                Output0Buffer.numPageViews = metric.numPageViews;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalPageViews = metric.numTotalPageViews;
                Output0Buffer.numTextPageViews = metric.numTextPageViews;
                Output0Buffer.numForwards = metric.numForwards;
                Output0Buffer.numTextForwards = metric.numTextForwards;
                Output0Buffer.numEstimatedForwards = metric.numEstimatedForwards;
                Output0Buffer.numTextEstimatedForwards = metric.numTextEstimatedForwards;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalEstimatedForwards = metric.numTotalEstimatedForwards;
                Output0Buffer.numReplies = metric.numReplies;
                Output0Buffer.numTextReplies = metric.numTextReplies;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalReplies = metric.numTotalReplies;
                Output0Buffer.numHardBounces = metric.numHardBounces;
                Output0Buffer.numTextHardBounces = metric.numTextHardBounces;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalHardBounces = metric.numTotalHardBounces;
                Output0Buffer.numSoftBounces = metric.numSoftBounces;
                Output0Buffer.numTextSoftBounces = metric.numTextSoftBounces;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalSoftBounces = metric.numTotalSoftBounces;
                Output0Buffer.numUnsubscribes = metric.numUnsubscribes;
                Output0Buffer.numTextUnsubscribes = metric.numTextUnsubscribes;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalUnsubscribes = metric.numTotalUnsubscribes;
                Output0Buffer.numIspComplaints = metric.numIspComplaints;
                Output0Buffer.numTextIspComplaints = metric.numTextIspComplaints;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalIspComplaints = metric.numTotalIspComplaints;
                Output0Buffer.numMailBlocks = metric.numMailBlocks;
                Output0Buffer.numTextMailBlocks = metric.numTextMailBlocks;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalMailBlocks = metric.numTotalMailBlocks;
                Output0Buffer.numSent = metric.numSent;
                Output0Buffer.numTextSent = metric.numTextSent;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalSent = metric.numTotalSent;
                Output0Buffer.numRecipientsClicked = metric.numRecipientsClicked;
                Output0Buffer.numDelivered = metric.numDelivered;
                Output0Buffer.numTextDelivered = metric.numTextDelivered;
                Output0Buffer.numTotalDelivered = metric.numTotalDelivered;
                Output0Buffer.percentageDelivered = metric.percentageDelivered;
                Output0Buffer.percentageUniqueOpens = metric.percentageUniqueOpens;
                Output0Buffer.percentageOpens = metric.percentageOpens;
                Output0Buffer.percentageUnsubscribes = metric.percentageUnsubscribes;
                Output0Buffer.percentageReplies = metric.percentageReplies;
                Output0Buffer.percentageHardBounces = metric.percentageHardBounces;
                Output0Buffer.percentageSoftBounces = metric.percentageSoftBounces;
                Output0Buffer.percentageUsersClicked = metric.percentageUsersClicked;
                Output0Buffer.percentageClicksToOpens = metric.percentageClicksToOpens ;             
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //FailComponent(e.ToString());
            if (e.Message != null)
            {
                string ExceptionMessage = e.Message;

            }

        }

    }

    /// <returns>An array of WorkGroupMetric composed of the de-serialized JSON</returns>
    private RootObject[] GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl, string base64)
    {

        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);

        httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
        HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        RootObject[] jsonResponse = null;

        try
        {
            //Test the connection
            if (httpWResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

            Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();
            dataLength = httpWResp.ContentLength;  

            string jsonString = null;

            //Set jsonString using a stream reader
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\\", "");
                reader.Close();
            }
            //Deserialize our JSON
            JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            jsonResponse = sr.Deserialize<RootObject[]>(jsonString);

            }
            //Output connection error message
            else
            {
                FailComponent(httpWResp.StatusCode.ToString());

            }
        }
        //Output JSON parsing error
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                if (ex.Message != null)
                {
                    string ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;

                }
        }
        return jsonResponse;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Outputs error message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorMsg">Full error text</param>
    private void FailComponent(string errorMsg)
    {
        bool fail = false;
        IDTSComponentMetaData100 compMetadata = this.ComponentMetaData;
        compMetadata.FireError(1, "Error Getting Data From Webservice!", errorMsg, "", 0, out fail);

    }

}
#endregion

#region JSON Class
//Class to hold our work group metrics


    public class RootObject
    {
        public DateTime dateSent { get; set; }
        public int numUniqueOpens { get; set; }
        public int numUniqueTextOpens { get; set; }
        public int numTotalUniqueOpens { get; set; }
        public int numOpens { get; set; }
        public int numTextOpens { get; set; }
        public int numTotalOpens { get; set; }
        public int numClicks { get; set; }
        public int numTextClicks { get; set; }
        public int numTotalClicks { get; set; }
        public int numPageViews { get; set; }
        public int numTotalPageViews { get; set; }
        public int numTextPageViews { get; set; }
        public int numForwards { get; set; }
        public int numTextForwards { get; set; }
        public int numEstimatedForwards { get; set; }
        public int numTextEstimatedForwards { get; set; }
        public int numTotalEstimatedForwards { get; set; }
        public int numReplies { get; set; }
        public int numTextReplies { get; set; }
        public int numTotalReplies { get; set; }
        public int numHardBounces { get; set; }
        public int numTextHardBounces { get; set; }
        public int numTotalHardBounces { get; set; }
        public int numSoftBounces { get; set; }
        public int numTextSoftBounces { get; set; }
        public int numTotalSoftBounces { get; set; }
        public int numUnsubscribes { get; set; }
        public int numTextUnsubscribes { get; set; }
        public int numTotalUnsubscribes { get; set; }
        public int numIspComplaints { get; set; }
        public int numTextIspComplaints { get; set; }
        public int numTotalIspComplaints { get; set; }
        public int numMailBlocks { get; set; }
        public int numTextMailBlocks { get; set; }
        public int numTotalMailBlocks { get; set; }
        public int numSent { get; set; }
        public int numTextSent { get; set; }
        public int numTotalSent { get; set; }
        public int numRecipientsClicked { get; set; }
        public int numDelivered { get; set; }
        public int numTextDelivered { get; set; }
        public int numTotalDelivered { get; set; }
        public double percentageDelivered { get; set; }
        public double percentageUniqueOpens { get; set; }
        public double percentageOpens { get; set; }
        public double percentageUnsubscribes { get; set; }
        public double percentageReplies { get; set; }
        public double percentageHardBounces { get; set; }
        public double percentageSoftBounces { get; set; }
        public double percentageUsersClicked { get; set; }
        public double percentageClicksToOpens { get; set; }
    }

#endregion
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing code, this is amazingly hard to troubleshoot

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annoyingly a colleague looked at the script and found nothing wrong with it that he could see was, so in a lateral-thinking moment, he created a new script component and *pasted* the c# script in, and after creating the interfaces, it worked!

Not sure, but perhaps there were some artifacts left over from the development of the script that were causing problems?

Comment: What a silly error, though I am glad someone else came across this and posted about it. Fixed my problem today.

Comment: @Marcus D : Thank you a lot. You saved my day. It works for me.

Comment: This is the one... why is the answer always cope and paste into a new object?

Comment: With this, it is perhaps that the SSIS/.net implementation isn't very tidy